# Access 2010-2016 Compatibility Error

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, vba, ms-access-2016

I was just updated to Access 2016, while my users are still at Access 2010.

I opened our database in MS Access 2016 once, didn't make any changes, and closed it out, and now all the users are having errors for **ANY** basic VBA code, including:

```
StrConv (Me.FormField, vbProperCase)
DoCmd.GoToRecord
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
```

etc.

However, it works fine on my end. Totally broken for all my users on Access 2010. Is there any way to fix this? I am thinking, even if I go back to Access 2010, if these are errors for code that would normally work fine in either version, how to I resolve these errors?

Tried a compact and repair, no effect.

Here's an example: In Access 2010,  when the `AfterUpdate()` event is triggered on a textbox that has the `StrConv (Me.FormField, vbProperCase)` function, it brings up the VBA debugger. 
The error is: **`Compile error: cannot find  project or library.`**

Previously, the exact same function worked fine in access 2010, and there have been no changes to this code. It works fine in a backup copy from about 15 days ago.

Answer (score 2):

*<sub>[Community wiki answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki):</sub>*

That particular error message is the key:

> Compile error: cannot find  project or library

Opening the office 2010 database in 2016 removed all of the VBA references to 14.0 Object Libraries in the References menu, and replaced them with 16.0, which is not present in Office 2010.

Broken references are to be expected when the `.mdb` is opened in an older version. It happens when there are references to Office libraries (Word, Excel, etc). Edit the references (in the VB Editor) in the oldest version (the one that doesn't run the code).

Answer (score 1):

First:
- Check for "Missing:Reference" in the Visual Basic Editor. Typically it's MS Access inheriting the new references and not reverting them or making them backwards compatible.

Second:
- Could also be the OLE Automation Reference acting up...remove the OLE Automation reference, save/close/reopen db, and add it back. I get this error from time to time when using Environ("Username").

Answer (score 0):

Some features which have been added to MS Access 2016 will restrict you few things like. 
You may not able to modify the object that uses the feature. Objects that uses the features will not open.So new features embedded in 2016 might be restricting file to open.
I cannot say accurately what changed.